# Using a custom function in a Laravel 5 Controller

Tags: function, laravel, controller, laravel-5

I'm using a Laravel 5, I just want to know how to use or declare a custom function inside my controller. I have

```
class UploadController extends Controller
{
  function on_request_done($content, $url, $ch, $search) {

    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);    
    if ($httpcode !== 200) {
        print "Fetch error $httpcode for '$url'\n";
        return;
    }
    $responseobject = json_decode($content, true);
    if (empty($responseobject['responseData']['results'])) {
        print "No results found for '$search'\n";
        return;
    }
    print "********\n";
    print "$search:\n";
    print "********\n";
    $allresponseresults = $responseobject['responseData']['results'];
    foreach ($allresponseresults as $responseresult) {
        $title = $responseresult['title'];
        print "$title\n";
    }
  }
}
```

And whenever I call `on_request_done` inside one of my functions let's say,

```
public function getParallelApi()
{
    define ('SEARCH_URL_PREFIX', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&rsz=large&filter=0');
    $terms_list = array(
        "John", "Mary",
        "William", "Anna",
        "James", "Emma",
        "George", "Elizabeth",
        "Charles", "Margaret",
        "Frank", "Minnie",
        "Joseph", "Ida",
        "Henry", "Bertha",
        "Robert", "Clara",
        "Thomas", "Alice",
        "Edward", "Annie",
        "Harry", "Florence",
        "Walter", "Bessie",
        "Arthur", "Grace",
        "Fred", "Ethel",
        "Albert", "Sarah",
        "Samuel", "Ella",
        "Clarence", "Martha",
        "Louis", "Nellie",
        "David", "Mabel",
        "Joe", "Laura",
        "Charlie", "Carrie",
        "Richard", "Cora",
        "Ernest", "Helen",
        "Roy", "Maude",
        "Will", "Lillian",
        "Andrew", "Gertrude",
        "Jesse", "Rose",
        "Oscar", "Edna",
        "Willie", "Pearl",
        "Daniel", "Edith",
        "Benjamin", "Jennie",
        "Carl", "Hattie",
        "Sam", "Mattie",
        "Alfred", "Eva",
        "Earl", "Julia",
        "Peter", "Myrtle",
        "Elmer", "Louise",
        "Frederick", "Lillie",
        "Howard", "Jessie",
        "Lewis", "Frances",
        "Ralph", "Catherine",
        "Herbert", "Lula",
        "Paul", "Lena",
        "Lee", "Marie",
        "Tom", "Ada",
        "Herman", "Josephine",
        "Martin", "Fanny",
        "Jacob", "Lucy",
        "Michael", "Dora",
    );

    if (isset($argv[1])) {
    $max_requests = $argv[1];
    } else {
        $max_requests = 10;
    }

    $curl_options = array(
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => FALSE,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Parallel Curl test script',
    );

    $parallel_curl = new ParallelCurl($max_requests, $curl_options);

    foreach ($terms_list as $terms) {
        $search = '"'.$terms.' is a"';
        $search_url = SEARCH_URL_PREFIX.'&q='.urlencode($terms);
        $parallel_curl->startRequest($search_url, 'on_request_done', $search);
    }


    $parallel_curl->finishAllRequests();

    //return "Helloo";
}
```

I get

`call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'on_request_done' not found or invalid function name`

My route

```
Route::get('/parallelapi', 'UploadController@getParallelApi');
```

PLEASE NOTE THAT `getParallelApi()` is under `UploadController` as well.

Comment: you are inside a class, try using `this -> on_request_done()` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are passing in the name of the function but it has no idea what class that function exists in.  You should be able to do this by passing an array as your callback with the first item being an instance of your controller and the second item being the name of the function.

```
$parallel_curl->startRequest($search_url, [$this, 'on_request_done'], $search);
```